# raise ValueError("No objects to concatenate") ValueError: No objects to concatenate

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path
import xlwings as xw

```
INPUT_DIR = Path(__file__).parent / "both"
files = list(INPUT_DIR.glob("*.xlsx"))

mapping_table = {"SROCode": "srocode", "InternalDocumentNumber": "internaldocumentnumber",
                 "DocNo": "docno", "DocName": "docname", "RegistrationDate": "registrationdate",
                 "SROName": "sroname", "SellerParty": "sellerparty", "PurchaserParty": "purchaserparty",
                 "PropertyDescription": "propertydescription", "AreaName": "areaname"}
dataframes = []
with xw.App(visible=False) as app:
    for file in files:
        wb = app.books.open(file)
        sht = wb.sheets[0]
        df = sht.tables["Table1"].range.options(pd.DataFrame, index=False).value
        df = df.rename(columns=mapping_table)
        df["Source Name"] = file.stem
        dataframes.append(df)
        wb.close()

    combined_df = pd.concat(dataframes)
    wb_combined = app.books.add()
    wb_combined.sheets[0].range("A1").options(pd.DataFrame, index=False).value = combined_df
    wb.save(Path(__file__).parent / "Combined_Data.xlsx")
    wb_combined.close()
```

[enter image description here][1]

I am getting following error message:

/Users/abhijitchavan/venv/bin/python /Users/abhijitchavan/PycharmProjects/FILE CONVERT/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/Users/abhijitchavan/PycharmProjects/FILE CONVERT/main.py", line 23, in 
combined_df = pd.concat(dataframes)

File "/Users/abhijitchavan/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 317, in wrapper
return func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/abhijitchavan/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py", line 369, in concat
op = _Concatenator(

File "/Users/abhijitchavan/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py", line 426, in **init**
raise ValueError("No objects to concatenate")

ValueError: No objects to concatenate

Comment: Seems like all of your code should be within the `for` identation.

Comment: can u please guid hoe to write code correctly

Comment: Do not post pictures of your code. It is easier if you post a reproducible example in your question.

Comment: @kgkmeekg yes . you are right. Sorry did not realise, as I'm new to this

Comment: Can you add the full traceback of the problem, which command, in which line does it happen. Thank you

Comment: @Daraan. yes I have copied traceback msg

Comment: (thx, you can wrap it in script tags as well for a better formatting). It could be that your for loop is never iterated and the list not filled. Can you check if your dataframes list is empty? how about your files list?

Comment: code works fine till wb.close()     Last five lines create issue

Comment: Try to print `file`. I'm pretty sure there are no files so nothing is added to `dataframes` which causes the concat function to throw an error