# python how to insert result of data frame into read_block function

Tags: python, pandas, regex, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to use the result of data frame that I generated from Azure Blob Storage and apply to the next step (where it extracts data in certain way).

I have tested both sides (generating data from Azure Blob Storage & extracting data using Regex (and it works if I tested separately)), but my challenge now is putting two pieces of code together.

Here is first part (getting data frame from Azure Blob Storage):

```
import re 
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
from azure.storage.blob import BlobClient


blob = BlobClient(account_url="https://test.blob.core.windows.net",
              container_name="xxxx",
              blob_name="Text.csv",
              credential="xxxx")

data = blob.download_blob()
df = pd.read_csv(data)
```

Here is second part (extracting only some parts from a csv file):

```
def read_block(names, igidx=True):
    with open("Test.csv") as f:   ###<<<This is where I would like to modify<<<###              
        pat = r"(\w+),+$\n[^,]+.+?\n,+\n(.+?)(?=\n,{2,})"
        return pd.concat([
            pd.read_csv(StringIO(m.group(2)), skipinitialspace=True)
                .iloc[:, 1:].dropna(how="all") for m in re.finditer(
                    pat, f.read(), flags=re.M|re.S) if m.group(1) in names # optional
        ], keys=names, ignore_index=igidx)

df2 = read_block(names=["Admissions", "Readmissions"],igidx=False).droplevel(1).reset_index(names="Admission")
```

So, what I am trying to do is use df from the first code and apply into the input section of second code where it says "with open ("Test.csv") as f.

How do I modify the second part of this code to take the data result from first part?

[image]

Or if that does not work, is there a way to use the file path ID (data) generated from Azure like below?

```
<azure.storage.blob._download.StorageStreamDownloader object at 0x00000xxxxxxx>
```

Update:

I modified the code as below, and now I am getting concat error:

I am not sure it is due to not having any looping function (as I modified to delete "with open("Test.csv") as f:).

```
...

data = blob.download_blob()
df = pd.read_csv(data)
df1 = df.to_csv(index=False, header=False)

def read_block(names, igidx=True):    
    pat = r"(\w+),+$\n[^,]+.+?\n,+\n(.+?)(?=\n,{2,})"
    return pd.concat([
        pd.read_csv(StringIO(m.group(2)), skipinitialspace=True)
            .iloc[:, 1:].dropna(how="all") for m in re.finditer(
                pat, df1, flags=re.M|re.S) if m.group(1) in names 
    ], keys=names, ignore_index=igidx)

df2 = read_block(names=["Admissions", "Readmissions"], igidx=False).droplevel(1).reset_index(names="Admission")   
print(df2)
```

[image]

New Image:

[image]

This is error message:
[image]

This is latest code (11/13/2023-1):

```
import re 
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
from azure.storage.blob import BlobClient
blob = 
BlobClient(account_url="https://xxxx.blob.core.windows.net",
              container_name="xxxx",
              blob_name="SampleSafe.csv",               
              credential="xxxx")

data = blob.download_blob(); 
df = pd.read_csv(data); 
df1 = df.to_csv(index=False)

def read_block(names, igidx=True):    
    pat = r"(\w+),+$\n[^,]+.+?\n,+\n(.+?)(?=\n,{2,})"
    return pd.concat([
        pd.read_csv(StringIO(m.group(2)), skipinitialspace=True)
            .iloc[:, 1:].dropna(how="all") for m in re.finditer(
                pat, data.readall(), flags=re.M|re.S)
               if m.group(1) in names], keys=names, ignore_index=igidx)

df2 = read_block(names=["Admissions", "Readmissions"], igidx=False).droplevel(1).reset_index(names="block")
print(df2)
```

This is detailed error message (updated 11/13/2023-1):

[image]

**This is df1 (11/18/2023):**

```
Division  FacilityName Census Admiss Readmiss  Discharges
          Test1         57    0      0         0
          Test3         2     0      0         1
          Test5         135   0      0         0
          Test6         9     0      0         0
          Test4         3     0      0         1
          Test2         76    0      0         0
          Blindsection  55    1      0         2
                
                
Admissions                  
Not Started: 12 Sent: 3 Completed: 3            
                
Division Community    ResiName  Date      DocStatus  LastUpdate
         TestStation  Jane Doe  9/12/2023 Sent       9/12/2023
         TestStation2 John Doe  9/12/2023 NotStarted    
         Alibaba      SuperMan  9/12/2023 NotStarted    
         Iceland      SuperWoma 9/12/2023 NotStarted    
                
                
Readmissions                    
Not Started: 1  Sent: 0 Completed: 1            
                
Division Community  ResidentName Date      DocStatus    Last Update
         StationK   PrettyWoman  9/12/2023 Not Started  
         MyGoodness UglyMan      7/21/2023 Completed    7/26/2023
                
                
Discharge                   
                
Division Community       ResidentName   Date        
         StationKingdom1 PrettyWoman2   8/22/2023       
         MyGoodness1     UglyMan1       4/8/2023        
         Landmark2       NiceGuys       9/12/2023       
         IcelandKingdom2 Mr.Heroshi2    7/14/2023       
         MoreKingdom2    KingKong       8/31/2023
```

[image]
This is error message from using previous code (updated 11/18):
[image]

**This is error message (updated 11/19):**
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. What does `df` has anything to do with the `read_block`? `with open('Test.csv') as f:` will try to read the `Test.csv` file from your local storage.

Comment: @QuangHoang So, I got the second part working at local drive (with help from someone). Now my challenge is taking the df from Azure and apply into the second logic.

Comment: Instead of `f.read()` just use `data` and see where that gets you.

Comment: @MarkRansom I tried, but the issue is how to modify the "with open( ) as f" part. So I tried with following (see Update), and now the error is AttributeError __enter__ . I also tried with using "data" instead of "f.read()", and got the same error.

Comment: Try using the output of `df.to_csv(index=False, header=False)`, **NOTE**: there may be extra special characters `\r` but rest should work fine.

Comment: @rr_goyal I modified the code (please see the Update2 on the top). I am not sure it is what you were thinking. I was not sure how to change the area where it has "with ... as f". But I am still getting the same error (AttributeError __enter__).

Comment: No `with` block, just replace `df1` instead of `f.read()`.

Comment: As @QuangHoang mentioned, replace f.read() with df1 and remove the with statement. The output of `df.to_csv(...)` is similar to `f.read()`.

Comment: You're too hung up on using `with`.  If you've already read in the data you don't need it, just get rid of it.

Comment: @QuangHoang I modified the code as shown on the top (Update). I am getting concat error.

Comment: Check if the list you are passing inside `concat` is producing the desirable output (or any output at all).

Comment: @rr_goyal Yes, when I debugged and hovered over df1, it populated data at (df1), but I think there is something to do with concat. I updated the content above with a new image. It loops around and when it reached the line 31, it creates error. Is indent wrong by chance?

Comment: You need to confirm if there is any data present in this list `[
        pd.read_csv(StringIO(m.group(2)), skipinitialspace=True)
            .iloc[:, 1:].dropna(how="all") for m in re.finditer(
                pat, df1, flags=re.M|re.S) if m.group(1) in names 
    ]` i.e. the list that is passed to concat and not just `df1`

Comment: @rr_goyal I am not sure how to check whether data is present inside [ ].  But, don't we have to put the second code within For .. or some type of looping (since we took out the With.. (the original pattern))? Please take a look at my updated code on the top.  I just saw this post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74127943/raise-valueerrorno-objects-to-concatenate-valueerror-no-objects-to-concaten)

Comment: @rr_goyal How do I check if there is any data present in this list? Where do I put the break point and where/how do I look?

Comment: @Java, can you `print(df)` or `print(df1)` and include it as text to your post ?

Comment: @Timeless I just posted it. It appears that, somehow, it did not get the line that indicates "Admissions".

Comment: What exactly is your expected output?

Answer (score 1):

> *I modified the code ... and now I am getting `concat` error* !

IIUC, that's because regex fails to match the required blocks. You need to remove `header=False` when making the *buffer* `df1 = df.to_csv(index=False)`. Or simply [`readall`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.storagestreamdownloader?view=azure-python#azure-storage-blob-storagestreamdownloader-readall) the downloaded blob and make a [*string*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-download-python#download-to-a-string) to avoid reading the input csv as a DataFrame :

```
data = blob.download_blob(max_concurrency=1, encoding="UTF-8")

def read_block(names, igidx=True):    
    pat = r"(\w+),+$\n[^,]+.+?\n,+\n(.+?)(?=\n,{2,})"
    return pd.concat([
        pd.read_csv(StringIO(m.group(2)), skipinitialspace=True)
            .iloc[:, 1:].dropna(how="all") for m in re.finditer(
                pat, data.readall(), flags=re.M|re.S)
               if m.group(1) in names], keys=names, ignore_index=igidx)
```

Comment: Thank you. Thankfully "Admissions" line shows up, but I am now getting "TypeError: expected string or bytes-lie object" error. I put the image on the top.

Comment: Seems like it is triggered by `re.finditer`. Which line you used to define `data` ? Have you tried passing `df1` `re.finditer` like in your original code ?

Comment: I am not sure what you meant by "passing df1 re.finditer like in your original code". I posted my latest code on the top.

Comment: I mean have you tried using `data = BytesIO(); blob.download_blob().readinto(data)` ? In your last code, you're using `data = blob.download_blob()` (which apparently triggers the `TypeError` when passed to `re.finditer`.

Comment: I tried with exact code you gave me and I updated the my latest code on the top. I am still getting TypeError expected string or byte-like object. But when I did print(data), this is what I get:    <_io.BytesIO object at 0x00000212EECF9B80>

Comment: Thanks for the debugging. I think I understand the problem now (*see updated answer*).

Comment: I tried with your updated code, but I am still getting "concat error". I updated the content with my latest code ("This is my latest code (third time):").

Comment: I feel like you’re not telling us all the details. If so, I give up. If not, can you `print(data.read().decode("utf-8"))` and include it as text to tour post ?

Comment: If I just do this:    data = BytesIO()     blob.download_blob().readinto(data)
   print(data.read().decode("utf-8")), nothing comes up. Is this right code?

Comment: Is this   blob.download_blob().readinto(data.seek(0)) right?   If I do and run read_block, I get this error:   'int' object has no attribute 'write'  (on that blob.download_blob... line)

Comment: No, I updated my answer. Can you check it out ?

Comment: I ran the code on my laptop, and got the "No objects to concatenate" error message, so I ran the same code at Virtual Machine, and added the detailed error message on the top.  I have a question. If do "print(data)", I get something like <azure.storage.blob._download.StorageStreamDownloader object at 0x00000B9EE400> Am I on the right track?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33091869/6361531

I think you need to use StringIO to convert that stream into strings and use read_csv to get dataframes.

Comment: Thank you @ScottBoston. @Java, can you try this ? Also, have you tried using `readall` ?

Comment: @ScottBoston Thank you. What is example of stream? Is it something like <azure.storage.blob._download.StorageStreamDownloader object at 0x00000B9xx400>?  I am trying many ways to make it work, but I would like some clue for an input that goes into "read_block".

Comment: @Java, again, have you **tried** `readall` (*see last update*) ? If you - each time -make 24 hours to reply, it will be difficult to help you.

Comment: @Timeless Yes, I tried, and getting the same concat error. I updated the latest code (& error message) on the top. Thank you!

Comment: Well, this doesn't make sense but in this case and as a workaround, use your initial approach `data = blob.download_blob(); df = pd.read_csv(data); df1 = df.to_csv(index=False)` (*as I mention at the beginning of my answer*) and pass `df1` to `re.finditer`.

Comment: @Timeless Sorry. what does it mean by  pass df1 to re.finditer?

Comment: `re.finditer(pat, df1, ...)`.

Comment: @Timeless I tried again & updated the code on the top (along with error message).

Comment: Yesterday, you said that you were able to `print(df1)`. Sorry but I give up because you're not telling all the truth. Good luck though ;)

Comment: @Timeless Yes. I am able to print(df1). Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @Timeless This might not be relevant to my original issue of this post. I am noticing similar pattern regards to "concat error". I tested with csv files at a local drive. When I used a csv file that I got from one place, I get the "concat error". But, when I open and save the same csv file, it populated data (no error). I am guessing my Visual Studio Code only runs when the file is safe (or saved)? Have you had any similar issue? I gave up using data from blob storage because I am still having an issue even when I run a csv file at a local drive.